# Drawing random lines from point to point (also generated random)

Tags: math, graphics, java, trigonometry

I need a little help with java.
I need to create some curves between two points.
Application needs to create a random number of curves that will
connect from random generated begin point to random generated end point.

Here is my code so far:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tryproject;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Q
 */
public class GUI extends JPanel{

    @Override

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        ArrayList<Point> jaa = new ArrayList<Point>();
 Random ja = new Random();
Random p = new Random();
int x = ja.nextInt(50) +50;
int y = ja.nextInt(150) + 150;
Point pocetnaTacka = new Point(Math.abs(ja.nextInt(150)),Math.abs(ja.nextInt(150)));
Point zavrsmaTacka = new Point(Math.abs(ja.nextInt(300) ) ,Math.abs(ja.nextInt(300)));
int lx = pocetnaTacka.x;

int ly = pocetnaTacka.y; 
jaa.add(pocetnaTacka);
int rastojanje = (pocetnaTacka.x - zavrsmaTacka.x)/10;

for (int i = 1;i< Math.abs(ja.nextInt(8));i++){
        x =  lx + Math.abs(ja.nextInt(50));
        y =  ly + Math.abs(ja.nextInt(50));
         jaa.add(new Point(x,y));
        lx = x;
        ly = y;
     }

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
             RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
jaa.add(zavrsmaTacka);
Point lastpp = (Point)pocetnaTacka.clone();
for(Point pp: jaa)
{
    QuadCurve2D q = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
// draw QuadCurve2D.Float with set coordinates
q.setCurve(lastpp.x, lastpp.y, pp.x/3, pp.y/3, pp.x, pp.y);

  g2.draw(q);

    lastpp = (Point) pp.clone();

}
for(Point aa: jaa)
{
    System.out.println(aa.x + " , "+aa.y);
}

    } 



}
```

This is how it should look but i cant get it like this:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2U/qT/4LubxcQN/everytime.png
And every time application runs Two new point will be generated and curves to ..
I tried with sin , cos functions but i can't get it to work between two point.
Can anybody help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is exactly the problem you are facing?

Comment: Well i cant get it to create those curves between two point smoothly . It generate curves but the curves is draw on another curve. I need clean curve connection from point from point with no overlap.

Comment: If points are created randomly you can not avoid ovelapping. Show what you get now.

Comment: Here is what i get now:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3x/N5/10zH3KcY/random.png
Here is what i should get:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2U/qT/4LubxcQN/everytime.png

Comment: I think it is the matter of points values, not drawing. It looks okay if points are generated differently. What is the logic behind your points selection?

Comment: Well all the points are randomly generated . i thought that it can be done with some mathematics formula but i am bad at Math :D.
I tried with Sin and Cos functions but the graphs are always the same and it can go only in the same X line witch is not good.
For this logic  i only created point by using the previus point and adding random to x and y axis.

Comment: It seems from the picture that points are not completely random. They follow some line and just deviate a little from it. Review that part.

Comment: That will not solve my problem . I need some math functions definitely.

Comment: No problem, just use it and fix the problem.

Comment: to fix the smoothness of the line in your code(not the overlap) you need to change the control points in the `q.setCurve(lastpp.x, lastpp.y, pp.x/3, pp.y/3, pp.x, pp.y);` line. in general you want to have the control point on the same line formed by the last point and the last control point. there's a bit of math to be done there but nothing too complicated. read up on [Quadratic Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tryproject2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Q
 */
public class GUI extends JPanel {


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        ArrayList<Point> jaa = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Random pocetnaikrajnja = new Random();
              RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                      RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Point pocetnaTacka = new Point(Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(150)), Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(200) + 100));
        g2.fillOval(pocetnaTacka.x,pocetnaTacka.y, 5, 5);


        jaa.add(pocetnaTacka);
        Point poslednjatacka = (Point) pocetnaTacka.clone();
        for (int i = 1;i< 6;i++){
            Point p = new Point(poslednjatacka.x + Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(30) + 30),pocetnaTacka.y - Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(30) + 30));
            poslednjatacka = p;
            jaa.add(p);
        }
         Point zavrsnaTacka  = null;

       zavrsnaTacka = new Point(jaa.get(jaa.size()-1).x+Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(15) + 15),jaa.get(jaa.size()-1).y-70);


        jaa.add(zavrsnaTacka);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillOval(zavrsnaTacka.x,zavrsnaTacka.y, 5, 5);
        for(int i=0;i<jaa.size()-1;i++)
        {

               QuadCurve2D q = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
//if(i%2==0){
q.setCurve(jaa.get(i).x, jaa.get(i).y,jaa.get(i).x/1.2,jaa.get(i).y-Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(35) + 35), jaa.get(i+1).x, jaa.get(i+1).y);
//}
//else
//{
  //  q.setCurve(jaa.get(i).x, jaa.get(i).y,jaa.get(i).x/1.2,jaa.get(i).y+Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(35) + 35), jaa.get(i+1).x, jaa.get(i+1).y);

//}
  g2.draw(q);
}
        /**
         * Sakriven kod za grane.
        for(int i=1;i<jaa.size()-Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(2)+1);i= i + Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(5)))
        {
              QuadCurve2D q = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
              if(i%2==0)
                q.setCurve(jaa.get(i).x, jaa.get(i).y,jaa.get(i).x/1.2,jaa.get(i).y/1.2, jaa.get(i).x + Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(5) + 7), jaa.get(i).y - Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(10) + 60));
              else
                    q.setCurve(jaa.get(i).x, jaa.get(i).y,jaa.get(i).x/1.2,jaa.get(i).y/1.2, jaa.get(i).x + Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(5) + 7), jaa.get(i).y + Math.abs(pocetnaikrajnja.nextInt(10) + 60));


              g2.draw(q);

        }
        */


    }
}
```